# Is it possible to switch the user on a git repo?

Tags: git, ssh, ssh-keys

We have a staging server that we use git to manage very simply: develop locally, git commit/push, and then git pull on the server. I'd love to be able to switch user on the server's copy so I could run the git pull rather than the person who set up the environment. Any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `chown -R` (or `chgrp -R` and `chmod -R g+w`) the repository you want to be able to `git pull` into. Git has no permission checking of its own, it defers that to whichever access mechanism you use. In case of local and SSH access, as you’re apparently using, that’s just regular OS file ownership.

Comment: Do you mean "the remote repository" (the bare repository that's acting as master) or the "working copy" (to use a svn term - the repository that's on the staging server)?

Comment: Whichever repository you want to be able to `git pull` into. (I’ve amended my answer to clarify.)

Comment: @pjmorse: Yes, Aristotle Pagaltzis means the remote bare repository. Everything git knows about the repo is in .git, so change the user on .git and you're good to go.

Comment: That’s not what I meant in this case, although at first I misunderstood the question in the same way as you did. (It’s not very clear on the workflow so it’s easy to misunderstand.) @NatchiQ has two “remote” repositories – a bare one he is pushing to, and another one for deployment that he pulls into from the bare repo. He can already push to the former but now also wants to be able to pull into the latter; so the latter is the one whose permissions he needs to fix.

Comment: (However – the same answer would apply if we were talking about the bare repository, since the Git repository is stored as simple files.)

Answer (score 4):

There is a great repo on github called gitswitch which will allow you to switch between git users: https://github.com/joealba/gitswitch

From the readme:

> Easily set/switch your current git user info for a git repo
>   .git/config or your global ~/.gitconfig file.
>
> This gem should come in handy if you have work and personal
>   repositories. It also might help with switching between users while
>   pair programming.
>
> Would you rather type “git config user.email ‘me@work.com’”, etc. or
>   type “gitswitch switch work”? If you answered the latter, check out
>   this gem.